# AES-256-GCM in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

im messing around with crypto in nodejs. I want to use aes-256-gcm algoritm but I have couple questions.. Just tell me if Im getting it right..

```
salt = crypto.randomBytes(64)
```

Salt is just a radom pseudo-data, right? Just to make our encrypted string harder to read?

I want to use createCipheriv method. Here's how I do it:

```
crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv)
```

First parameter is our algorithm, then we got our secret key (for encryption and decryption) and the last one is IV. What exactly does it mean apart from changing the encrypted string appearance? IV should be changing every time we want to encrypt something, right?

```
tag = cipher.getAuthTag();
```

What does tag mean exactly? Why do we need it?

Comment: Oh.. thats kinda obvious.. What about the rest ones?

Comment: Auth tag? IV? I guess it has something to do with authorization and iv changing the output but what exactly? I have read the docs but.. still im not quite sure about thtat.

Comment: Authentication, not authorization.

Comment: good point ;) i meant authentication, Its a signature of each encrypted data or something?

Comment: It verifies that the message has not been altered. It is designed into GCM mode, other modes can add authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function of a salt is to ensure two encryptions of the same data with the same key do not produce the same encrypted data.

It should be a different random value for each encryption. Since it does not need to be secret it can be a prefix the the encrypted so the decryption function will have it available.

Imagine a message sent every day go either "buy " or "sell", it would become obvious what the message meant.

The tag is part of the authentication that ensures the encrypted message has not been altered.

GCM mode is a form of authenticated encryption that also does not require message padding.

Comment: From his question it seems likely that he has both a salt and an IV. I assumed the salt was part of a password-based KDF and the IV was just the AES-GCM nonce.

Comment: One would hope.